# How to do a clickable file path in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file

I am trying to get a clickable file path using asp.net c# visual studios web form, meaning to say that it is like windows file explorer, allowing the person to navigate through the different levels of folders etc, can anyone provide any links to help get me started?  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyyLq.png

Comment: Are you looking for [asp:FileUpload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload?view=netframework-4.8)? This will allow the user to click on a button and search through files and upload one. You don't mention what you want to do with the file explorer. Are you uploading, Trying to download, etc?

Comment: @dvo I attached the image above, its something that I would like to do, not sure if that is counted as fileupload

Comment: It's still unclear what you're attempting to do... What is your end goal?

Comment: @dvo The end go is to allow users to access different levels of folders, just like how file explorer work, navigating through the directory

Answer (score 0):

You could try to get the path string and divide it in multiple pieces. Then store them in multiple textboxes, labels, buttons or whatever you want. My form looks like this: [Picture Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hgjb.png)

Secondly, you will have to update those (in my case) textboxes to save the path. See my code and decide what you want to use, and if you have to modify it.

```
private void changePath()
    {
        String path = webBrowser1.Url.AbsolutePath;
        if (path.Contains(@"/")) { path = path.Replace(@"/", @"\"); }
        string[] directories = path.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
        int count = directories.Count();

        if (count <= 6)
        {
            textBox1.Text = ""; textBox2.Text = ""; textBox3.Text = ""; textBox4.Text = ""; textBox5.Text = ""; textBox6.Text = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                String txt = "textBox" + (i + 1);
                TextBox tbx = this.Controls.Find(txt, true).FirstOrDefault() as TextBox;
                tbx.Text = directories[i];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            int p = count / 6;

            int z = count - (p * 6);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {

                int g = i - 1;
                String txt = "textBox" + (i + 1);
                TextBox tbx = this.Controls.Find(txt, true).FirstOrDefault() as TextBox;
                tbx.Text = directories[z];
                z++;
                if (i == 5)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Second step is to make click functions on the (in my case) textboxes. Here is one sample of how you can do this. See for yourself what you can do.

```
private void textBox5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!textBox5.Text.Equals(String.Empty))
        {
            String p = webBrowser1.Url.AbsolutePath;
            if(!textBox6.Text.Equals(String.Empty))
            {
                webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(p.Replace(@"/" + textBox6.Text, ""));
            }
        }
    }
```

This code will remove the last piece, leaving you with a new path. Example:

> Before: C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\C#

After:

> After: C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop

Again, you have to look what works for you. There are multiple ways to resolve your issue.

Good Luck!

Twan.

Comment: Thank you for the help!! Will give it a try @Twan